# Copy a movable object in C++20?

Tags: c++, move, c++20

Since I have declared a move constructor for a class, I can't copy it, what can I do?

```cpp
struct T
{
    T(T&&) {}
    T() {}
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    T* t = new T();
    T t2 = T();
    *t = t2; // error: constexpr T& T::operator=(const T&)' is implicitly declared as deleted because 'T' declares a move constructor or move assignment operator
}
```

What am I supposed to do if I don't want to implement `operator=`?

Why: I am trying to rewrite `std::vector` for learning purposes, and in the push back, I received an object which has a move constructor, and now I can't copy to the end of the array :/

Comment: you can declare a defaulted assignment operator=

Comment: I am trying to rewrite `std::vector` for learning purposes, and in the push back function I received an object which doesn't implement it :/ std::vector handles it well but my code doesn't compile

Comment: Do you need to copy it? Can you just move instead? e.g. `*t = std::move(t2)`?

Comment: You're supposed to start wanting to implement it, or stop wanting to use it, or to remove the user defined move. Defining the assignment as defaulted isn't much work.

Comment: A function emulating `std::vector::push_back` should **not** require assignment.  `push_back` constructs a new object in the vector.  It does not assign a new value to an existing object.

Comment: @DrewDormann By construction you mean using placement new or std::construct_at?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Doesn't work with the same error message

Comment: If you want to assign you need to implement the assignment operator

Comment: @Null2 Yes, either using placement new or - if you are planning to make your container usable in `constexpr` contexts - `std::construct_at`.

Comment: @DrewDormann Thanks! It worked after removing every assignment operator

Comment: I would say that push_back copies a new object into the vector. emplace_back constructs a new object.

Comment: @Null2 Great!  I will not post that as an answer, because I don't think my solution is acually answering the posted question of "I can't copy it, what can I do?".  I think your actual question was "How can I implement push back functionality without using the assignment operator?"